# Wordpress WP_QUERY with GET and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Recently I've been developing on a Wordpress theme, where you can filter different products (A post type) based on custom fields (metaboxes).
After a lot of hard work, I finally found a way to do it, by using the "array" from "get" url, check if it's set and if it is, then pass the array into the WP_QUERY.
Hope this image explains it a bit better

[image]

I'm doing it with this code: http://pastebin.com/T5ihsCw3

But now I would really like to update the query, every time a checkbox is checked (or unchecked), by using Ajax. I just can't get it to work, because I NEED to use the "GET" from the URL, and I can't find a guide on THAT specific thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Frederik

Comment: I don't see the problem. Javascript can easily edit the content of the url bar. You have just to "relate" the query string passed to the URL to your AJAX code. Extract the query string from the URL, and if you're using GET with your AJAX request, just use the query string as URL of the AJAX request. If you're using POST, deparam the query string into an object and send it via your AJAX request.

Comment: fixed some grammatical errors and putting the image in the question

Answer (score 0):

See this post. It shall give you an idea on how to solve your problem:

[WordPress: How to get metadata of Custom Fields from Custom Taxonomy with using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747463/wordpress-how-to-get-metadata-of-custom-fields-from-custom-taxonomy-with-using/36757550#36757550)

You need to create a function that can be queried by Ajax and then every time one of the checkboxes is checked, you just issue an Ajax get request.

Comment: Hey @neoprezthank you for your response, it certainly helped me to get a bit further in my development. Now my next problem is, that i don't really know how to progress from here. I've added basic Ajax functionality, so every time a checkbox is checked (or unchecked) a function is called. But i really can't figure out what to do from now, would you mind helping me? My new code: http://pastebin.com/DC1r0aRp  THANK YOU very much for your help, it really is appreciated!